# How to transform a php $string into a $string() function call?

Tags: php, function

My current code:

```
$operation = "alienFunction";
switch($operation){
        case "alphaFunction":
            alphaFunction();
            break;
        case "betaFunction":
            betaFunction();
            break;
        case "alienFunction":
            alienFunction($kidsPerPlanet, $planet);
            break;
```

Ok, I have a big list of functions. Some functions have parameters and some have not. The $operation is received from a $_POST variable. I want to do something like this:

```
$operation = "alphafunction";
$operation();
```

Or

```
$operation = "alienFunction";
$operation($kidsPerPlanet, $planet);
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). Also you may want to look into the factory pattern to avoid such a huge `switch`.

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already written in the comments you are looking for [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). Just use it like this:

```
call_user_func_array($functionName, $argumentArray);
```

But since you don't know which function you call with which parameters, just define an array and then use the code above, e.g.

```
$arguments = [
        "alphaFunction" => [],
        "betaFunction" => [],
        "alienFunction" => [$kidsPerPlanet, $planet],
    ];

call_user_func_array($functionName, $arguments[$functionName]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent.
Thanks, guys. For functions with no parameters, it's working perfectly.
I'm trying this now:

```
$userInfo = MySQL_FETCH_ARRAY( MySQL_QUERY( ($autoAuth) ) );
CALL_USER_FUNC_ARRAY($operation, $userInfo);
```

Inside of one of functions, I have this piece of code inserted into HTML:

```
ECHO "<p>" . VAR_DUMP($userInfo) . "</p>";
```

And the result gives me "string(2) "25".

I'm new here. So I don't know what to do. For sure, my question is answered. Now I know how to use a string to call a function. Should I close this, select the best answer and create another question? Should I let it open, while my WHOLE problem is solved? Or should I close it and still comment here to get feedback?

Thanks a lot. I'm loving this. I wish that I can contribute as soon as possible too. :)

Comment: The best would have been to write this as a comment. But I don't really see what the question now is here. Maybe you want to write a new separate question where you explain what your exact problem is. (Make sure you include: Your current code, your current output and your expected output into your question)

Comment: Ok, thank you. :)
The question was that the CALL_USER_FUNC_ARRAY($operation, $userInfo) was giving an string to my function. So, I've changed it to 

    CALL_USER_FUNC_ARRAY($operation, array($userInfo)); 
:)

Comment: ^ Nice, that you could figure it out. Yes as the function name already says, `call_user_func_array()` takes an array as arguments for the function